# Can I set key to only the key attribute that I move the bone along with?

Tags: animation

For example: I grab the Z axis and  move the bone upward, then I want to have only the Z axis location keyed, not the whole three axis xyz location nor other attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  If you right-click on the Z value in the N panel you get a menu, and one of the options is `Insert Single Keyframe`

[image: keyframe menu]